# CardView height doesn't transition with nested RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a nested RecyclerView in which the parent view is a CardView [( gif )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erxO4.gif).  I'm trying to implement a swipe to delete action by Paul Burke [( link )](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.4el48or0o). The action transitions nicely within the inner RecyclerView, but causes the outer CardView's height (wrap_content) to jump. Is there a way to make the CardView transition with the RecyclerView?

Inner RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_tasks_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_tasks_title"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="section placeholder" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/card_tasks_rv"
            android:background="#E0E0E0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Inner Item:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_task_project"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Project name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_task_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#757575"
            tools:text="Task name"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/item_task_divider" style="@style/Divider"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the CardView as the parent in your item layout, and have that load into your RecyclerView, like this:

Your container:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_tasks_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_tasks_title"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="section placeholder" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/card_tasks_rv"
            android:background="#E0E0E0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inner item:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="2dp">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_task_project"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Project name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_task_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#757575"
            tools:text="Task name"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/item_task_divider" style="@style/Divider"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: The CardView is a (perhaps redundant?) container for the nested RecyclerView. If I were to put the CardView in the inner item, wouldn't it create a cardview for every item? Thank you for your response.